# How to use __setattr__ correctly, avoiding infinite recursion

Tags: python, python-2.7, getattr, setattr

I want to define a class containing `read` and `write` methods, which can be called as follows:

```
instance.read
instance.write
instance.device.read
instance.device.write
```

To not use interlaced classes, my idea was to overwrite the `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` methods and to check, if the given name is `device` to redirect the return to `self`. But I encountered a problem giving infinite recursions. The example code is as follows:

```
class MyTest(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name=="device":
            print "device test"
        else:
            setattr(self, name, value)

test = MyTest(1)
```

As in `__init__` the code tried to create a new attribute `x`, it calls `__setattr__`, which again calls `__setattr__` and so on. How do I need to change this code, that, in this case, a new attribute `x` of `self` is created, holding the value `1`?

Or is there any better way to handle calls like `instance.device.read` to be 'mapped' to `instance.read`?

As there are always questions about the why: I need to create abstractions of `xmlrpc` calls, for which very easy methods like `myxmlrpc.instance,device.read` and similar can be created. I need to 'mock' this up to mimic such multi-dot-method calls.

Comment: this use case would be more easily solved using @property

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You must call the parent class `__setattr__` method:

```
class MyTest(object):

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name=="device":
            print "device test"
        else:
            super(MyTest, self).__setattr__(name, value)
            # in python3+ you can omit the arguments to super:
            #super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

Regarding the best-practice, since you plan to use this via `xml-rpc` I think this is probably better done inside the [`_dispatch`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html#SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer.register_instance) method.

A quick and dirty way is to simply do:

```
class My(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.device = self
```

Comment: I like the quick-and-dirty way: Just one line to get the desired behaviour! Thanks

Comment: This is also mentioned in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__).

Comment: @Bakuriu would you please explain what this line is doing exactly?
super(MyTest, self).__setattr__(name, value)

Comment: @Shahryar It is explained in the first line of my answer. It is calling the parent class `__setattr__` method. `super(Class, instance)` creates an object that is able to call the methods of the *parent class of `Class`* on `instance`. You could also do `object.__setattr__(instance, name, value)` in this case but `super` is able to handle correctly multi-inheritance and should be preferred.

Comment: why can't we simply say self[name] = value? is it wrong?

Comment: @Shahryar Because that's not even valid python syntax. `self[name] = value` is equivalent to `self.__setitem__(name, value)` which most of the time is not implemented. And if you try to use the `setattr` builtin what would happen is that `setattr(self, name value)` will recursively call `__setattr__` and you end up in an infinite  loop.

Answer (score 32):

Or you can modify `self.__dict__` from inside `__setattr__()`:

```
class SomeClass(object):

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print(name, value)
        self.__dict__[name] = value

    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = attr2


sc = SomeClass(attr1=1, attr2=2)

sc.attr1 = 3
```

Comment: Why does this not call `setattr(self, "__dict__", value)`, repeating the original infinite recursion problem?

Comment: Because this is not setting the `__dict__` attribute, gut getting it and then setting an item on the returned dict, i.e., it's calling sth like: `getattr(self, "__dict__").__setitem__(name, value)`

Answer (score 6):

You can also use **object**.

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
            self.data = 'data'
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
            print("Attempt to edit the attribute %s" %(name))
            object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
```

Comment: This a builtin class. All classes inherits from this class (even `__setattr__`, `__getattr__`, `__dict__`, ...)

Comment: similar to type then ?

Answer (score 4):

or you can just use @property:

```py
class MyTest(object):

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def device(self):
        return self
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to specify which attributes can or cannot be set, you can split the class to delay the get/set hooks until after initialization:

```py
class MyTest(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.__class__ = _MyTestWithHooks

class _MyTestWithHooks(MyTest):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        ...
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = MyTest(12)
    ...
```

As noted in the code you'll want to instantiate MyTest, since instantiating _MyTestWithHooks will result in the same infinite recursion problem as before.