# Meaning of self.__dict__ = self in a class definition

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand the following snippet of code:

```
class Config(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self
```

What is the purpose of the line `self.__dict__ = self`? I suppose it overrides the default `__dict__` function with something that simply returns the object itself, but since `Config` inherits from `dict` I haven't been able to find any difference with the default behavior.

Comment: Since it inherits from `dict`I don't get what it is trying to do ...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984647/accessing-dict-keys-like-an-attribute

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assigning the dictionary `self` to `__dict__` allows attribute access and item access:

```
>>> c = Config()
>>> c.abc = 4
>>> c['abc']
4
```

Comment: I also tested that this behavior requires the `self.__dict__ = self` line in the `__init__` (if `Config` is derived from `dict` only, I get a `NameError` trying to call `c['abc']`).

Comment: Assigning to `__dict__` is always a bad idea.  Please don't.  You can implement the actually desired behavior via `__setattr__` without all the other side effects.

Comment: @gps actually it's the opposite, I've tried a million ways to implement get/set attrib methods and always ends up with infinite recursion

Comment: @TheGhostOfGaussPossessesMe that can be resolved by calling `super().__setattr__(name, value)` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020115/how-to-use-setattr-correctly-avoiding-infinite-recursion

Answer (score 12):

As per [Python Document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__), `object.__dict__` is:

> A dictionary or other mapping object used to store an object’s (writable) attributes.

Below is the sample example:

```
>>> class TestClass(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.a = 5
...         self.b = 'xyz'
... 
>>> test = TestClass()
>>> test.__dict__
{'a': 5, 'b': 'xyz'}
```

Comment: How would you reverse this? I mean going from the dictionary to the keys..